# Output fractional amount of "incorrect" values in an array with python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a method that will predict some data and output it to a numpy array, called `Y_predict`. I then have a numpy array called `Y_real` which stores the real values of `Y` that should have been predicted.

For example:

```
Y_predict = [1, 0, 2, 1]
Y_real    = [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I then want an array called `errRate[]` which will check if `Y_predict[i] == Y_real[i]`. Any value that does not match `Y_real` should be noted. Finally, the output should be the amount of correct predictions. In the case above, this would be `0.75` since `Y_predict[2] = 2` and `Y_real[2] = 1`

Is there some way either in numpy or python to quickly compute this rate?

Answer (score 3):

Since they're numpy arrays, this is relatively straightforward:

```
>>> p
array([1, 0, 2, 1])
>>> r
array([1, 0, 1, 1])
>>> p == r
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> (p == r).mean()
0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Given these lists:

```
Y_predict = [1, 0, 2, 1]
Y_real    = [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

The easiest way I can think of is using zip() within a list comp:

```
Y_rate         = [int(x == y) for x, y in zip(Y_predict, Y_real)] # 1 if correct, 0 if incorrect
Y_rate_correct = sum(Y_rate) / len(Y_rate)

print( Y_rate_correct ) # this will print 0.75
```